# Get the first day of a month in swift

Tags: swift, calendar

I'm looking for a way to get the first day of a month (in Swift).
I would like to know if it is a Monday, Tuesday etc... by returning the number corresponding.

I try many solution like getting a NSCalendar component .weekDay but no one work.

```
Example :

print(getTheFirstDate("2016-2-18"))

// Should return : 0 (because the first day of February 2016 is Monday).
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Lots of methods here (Objective-C and Swift): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717574/get-firstdate-lastdate-of-month.

Comment: If my answer was correct please mark it as correct that way people know it is credible information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to get the corresponding number of the day of the week you can use:

```
var weekday = calendar!.component(NSCalendarUnit.Weekday, fromDate: yourNSDate)
var weekdayName = self.getDayOfWeek(weekday)
```

Then you can call this function I created to get the corresponding name of the day of the week based on the number passed in to *getDayOfWeek()*

```
func getDayOfWeek(weekday:Int) -> String {
        if(weekday == 1) {
            return "Sunday"
        }
        else if(weekday == 2) {
            return "Monday"
        }
        else if(weekday == 3) {
            return "Tuesday"
        }
        else if(weekday == 4) {
            return "Wednesday"
        }
        else if(weekday == 5) {
            return "Thursday"
        }
        else if(weekday == 6) {
            return "Friday"
        }
        else {
            return "Saturday"
        }

    }
```

**And if you are using a String as a date to begin with you can change it into an NSDate like this:**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /*place date format here*/
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(/*your_date_string*/)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I am pretty sure this is a solution.

Comment: That's not me, but when i try your code with :
`let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-d"

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-4-1")

let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

var weekday = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Weekday, fromDate: date!)`

weekday is equal to 6, but the answer was 4

Comment: That is correct. 2016-4-1 is a Friday. The format is year-month-day.

Comment: Oh god, you're right !
I'm French, so the week begin Monday.

So for me, friday is 5... My bad

Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Do not use the `getDayOfWeek` function with the hardcoded weekday names. `[NS]DateFormatter` already provide a way to get the weekday names from a weekday number.

Comment: You should be using `weekdaySymbols`, `shortWeekdaySymbols`, or `veryShortWeekdaySymbols`. This can take into account user local for translation purposes. It's also much cleaner to pull a value from an array than using a verbose switch statement.

Answer (score 9):

First you need to parse your date string, then you can use Calendar method dateComponents to get the calendar, year and month components from that date and create a new date from those components. Then you can extract the weekday date component from it:

**Xcode 11.5 • Swift 5.2**

```
extension Date {
    var weekday: Int { Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self) }
    var firstDayOfTheMonth: Date {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.calendar, .year,.month], from: self).date!
    }
}
```

---

```
extension String {
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var date: Date? {
       String.dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}

"2016-2-18".date?.firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday   // 2 = Monday (Sunday-Saturday 1-7)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension Date {
   var startOfWeek: Date {
      let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
      return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday!)!
   }

   var endOfWeek: Date {
      let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
      return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday!)!
   }

   var startOfPreviousWeek: Date {
      let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
      return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: -6, to: sunday!)!
   }

   var endOfPreviousWeek: Date {
      let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
      return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: sunday!)!
   }

   var startDateOfMonth: Date {
      return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!
   }

   var endDateOfMonth: Date {
      return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: self.startDateOfMonth)!
   }

   var getPreviousMonthDate: Date {
      return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self)!
   }

   var startDateOfPreviousMonth: Date {
      return getPreviousMonthDate.startDateOfMonth
   }

   var endOfPreviousMonth: Date {
      return getPreviousMonthDate.endDateOfMonth
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Leo's answer, but in case you want to encapsulate the logic into a single function or don't want to use extensions.

```
func getDayOfWeekForFirstDayOfMonthFromDateString(dateString:String) -> String? {

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
        if let firstOfMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: date)) {
            formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
            return formatter.stringFromDate(firstOfMonth)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

EDIT: Adjusted code to utilize Leo's great suggestion, and borrowed his more terse creation of the creation of the first of the month object. Thanks, Leo!

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. You should use NSDateFormatter to get the weekday name and without  language restrictions http://stackoverflow.com/a/36511646/2303865