# Swift UI calendar without packages

Tags: swift, swiftui

Had a stab at making a Calendar in swift ui without packages etc. I have it semi working but have the problem that all sundays are 1st, monads the 2nd, tuesday the 3rd etc. Having trouble rearranging these so that the date numbers actually line up with real world days. Any ideas where im going wrong

```
struct CustomCalendarView: View {
let calendar = Calendar.current
let daysOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
@State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                navigateToPreviousMonth()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 8)

            Text(monthYearFormatter.string(from: selectedDate))
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)

            Button(action: {
                navigateToNextMonth()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 8)
        }

        HStack {
            ForEach(daysOfWeek, id: \.self) { day in
                Text(day)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }

        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 7)) {
            ForEach(1...daysInMonth(date: selectedDate), id: \.self) { day in
                Text("\(day)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(8)
                    .background(dayBackgroundColor(for: day))
                    .foregroundColor(dayForegroundColor(for: day))
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectDate(day: day)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    .padding()
}

private func selectDate(day: Int) {
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: selectedDate)
    components.day = day
    guard let updatedDate = calendar.date(from: components) else {
        return
    }
    selectedDate = updatedDate
}

private func daysInMonth(date: Date) -> Int {
    guard let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date) else {
        return 0
    }
    return range.count
}

private func dayBackgroundColor(for day: Int) -> Color {
    let isCurrentMonth = calendar.isDate(selectedDate, equalTo: Date(), toGranularity: .month)
    let isSelected = calendar.isDate(selectedDate, equalTo: date(withDay: day), toGranularity: .day)
    return isCurrentMonth && isSelected ? .blue : .clear
}

private func dayForegroundColor(for day: Int) -> Color {
    let isCurrentMonth = calendar.isDate(selectedDate, equalTo: Date(), toGranularity: .month)
    let isSelected = calendar.isDate(selectedDate, equalTo: date(withDay: day), toGranularity: .day)
    return isCurrentMonth && isSelected ? .white : .primary
}

private func date(withDay day: Int) -> Date {
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: selectedDate)
    components.day = day
    return calendar.date(from: components) ?? Date()
}

private var monthYearFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    return formatter
}()

private func navigateToPreviousMonth() {
    guard let previousMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: selectedDate) else {
        return
    }
    selectedDate = previousMonth
}

private func navigateToNextMonth() {
    guard let nextMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: selectedDate) else {
        return
    }
    selectedDate = nextMonth
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the first day of a month in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093134/get-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking the problem down, this is what needs to be done:

1. find the day-of-week of the start of the month. You can do that by using [one of the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093134/get-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-swift).
2. calculate how many spaces to leave out in the grid, based on the day-of-week of the start of the month.
3. use a `ForEach` to make that many `Spacer`s in your grid.

So, write such a method for the first two steps:

```
private func numberOfLeadingSpacesInMonth(of date: Date) -> Int {
    guard let startOfMonth = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .year,.month], from: date).date else {
        return 0
    }
    let weekdayOfStartOfMonth = calendar.component(.weekday, from: startOfMonth)
    // a value of 1 means Sunday, so we subtract one
    return weekdayOfStartOfMonth - 1
}
```

And add a `ForEach` before the existing `ForEach` in the grid:

```
ForEach(0..<numberOfLeadingSpacesInMonth(of: selectedDate), id: \.self) { i in
    Spacer().id("Spacer \(i)")
}
```

Note that you should specify an `id` for each of the `Spacer`s. Otherwise, the `ForEach` will automatically assign an `id`, some of which will be the same `id` as the ones that the `Text`s get from the second `ForEach`. Duplicate ids will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks took a lot of playing but this this really helped, kind of got it to a way that im happy with.